# i cant draw a lineRenderer in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have been trying for a few hours now to make my turret shoot a laser. (the turret is at 0,0,0.)

here is my code so far. (this makes the turret point and draw the line on click)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtMouse : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]

    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private Transform _turretBarrel;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Ray rayOrigin = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, out hitInfo))
        {
            if (hitInfo.collider != null)
            {
                Vector3 direction = hitInfo.point - _turretBarrel.position;
                _turretBarrel.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
                {
                    //draw line from turret position to hitInfo.point
                    Debug.Log(hitInfo);
                    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, hitInfo.point);
                }
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also im not very good at implementing unity to C#

Answer (score 0):

1. You are only setting a single point as far as I can tell. To draw lines you gotta call `SetPosition` at least twice on every update. Probably once at turret location (0,0,0) and then once at the hit location like you currently do.
2. Not 100% sure but you might need to separate the collision checking from the drawing. You put the raycast rightfully in FixedUpdate (because it is physics-related) but drawing-related things are supposed to be in the normal `Update()` function (because that one is called every time the screen is redrawn).
   Thus save the position in a variable like `current_target` and draw the line between 0 and that target in the `Update()`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to set the `lineRenderer.positionCount`. Also you need at least two points to draw a line.

You can try the following code, I commented the changes.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    private Transform _turretBarrel;

    void Start()
    {
        // must set position count, otherwise no line is drawn
        lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;

        // set first point to barrel position
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, _turretBarrel.position);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Ray rayOrigin = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin, out hitInfo))
        {
            if (hitInfo.collider != null)
            {
                Vector3 direction = hitInfo.point - _turretBarrel.position;
                _turretBarrel.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
                {
                    //draw line from turret position to hitInfo.point
                    Debug.Log(hitInfo);

                    // set second point to hit position
                    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hitInfo.point);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```